Verification of JWT created in Postman using ES512 is unstable
I am using the following approach to create and sign JWT (ES512) in Postman (pre-script):
var CryptoJS  = require("crypto-js");
var navigator = {};
var window    = {};

eval(pm.globals.get("jsrsasign-js"));

let issuerId   = pm.environment.get("issuerId");
let audienceId = pm.environment.get("audienceId");
let privateKey = pm.environment.get("privateKey");

let body     = pm.request.body.raw;    
let bodyHash = calculateHash(body);

const pl     = payload(issuerId, audienceId, bodyHash)
const jwt    = signJwt(pl, privateKey)

pm.collectionVariables.set("bearerToken", jwt);

function calculateHash(message) {
  const hash = CryptoJS.SHA256(message??'');
  return hash.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64);
}

function payload(iss, aud, bodyHash) {
  return {
    "iss": iss,
    "aud": aud,
    "sub": "api-request",
    "rbh": bodyHash,
    "exp": Math.round(Date.now() / 1000) + 59,
  };
}

function signJwt(payload, privateKey) {
  const alg      = 'ES512';
  const header   = {"alg":alg};
  const sHeader  = JSON.stringify(header);
  const sPayload = JSON.stringify(payload);
  return KJUR.jws.JWS.sign('ES512', sHeader, sPayload, privateKey);
}

Private key is generated:
openssl ecparam -name secp521r1 -genkey -noout -out private.pem

Public key:
openssl ec -in private.pem -pubin -outform PEM -out public.pem

Server uses: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.nimbusds/nimbus-jose-jwt/9.40 to verify JWT:
ECDSAVerifier(parseFromPEMEncodedObjects(publicKey).toECKey())

Jwt verification is quite unstable. Sometimes it succeeds (80%), sometimes fails (20%).
The reason is that sometimes jws signature length is 130 bytes (not OK), should be 132, sometimes 132.
OK JWT: eyJhbGciOiJFUzUxMiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJhZTA3YmE1My0xOTYwLTRiMDYtYTYyZi01ZjdkYjRkYWM3MGYiLCJhdWQiOiJkMF9ha0IyNWJZaDNtI1ByekVmPHVLMXZRTGp7Q3hweUdIUHRMWkwpIiwic3ViIjoib3BlbmFwaS1yZXF1ZXN0IiwicmJoIjoiY2FyZ3VqY3lINHJiSDl0U3BxVWo4dFpkZmM0eHUyL1dvOGZJbzJYek1Nbz0iLCJleHAiOjE3MjI3NDc4NTV9.AJTc6e_4ymPhtQPSx6XoeYyOScFIYf5axTrSTXz2rtXuH9KZAFZBuoTMD35siR7-MIpRpIk2QslSNvU4A7KQSUVFAeH0Mb7yfwC2bN5ncJhWxg6j5dh6sJfPwLi3buGuw9i_TViF6mnLs8WClzXw8NqFBoNSnHexQPkWba8J-trAxoKo
Not OK JWT:    eyJhbGciOiJFUzUxMiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJhZTA3YmE1My0xOTYwLTRiMDYtYTYyZi01ZjdkYjRkYWM3MGYiLCJhdWQiOiJkMF9ha0IyNWJZaDNtI1ByekVmPHVLMXZRTGp7Q3hweUdIUHRMWkwpIiwic3ViIjoib3BlbmFwaS1yZXF1ZXN0IiwicmJoIjoiY2FyZ3VqY3lINHJiSDl0U3BxVWo4dFpkZmM0eHUyL1dvOGZJbzJYek1Nbz0iLCJleHAiOjE3MjI3NDc5MTZ9.gcJl3McLyAML3nfbb-ZXXtvfP-TRm0rjpEYX7iiagiFGSNoMi-8yu7jre_QTB0SW2_POrp4OcGg0QY2EeRCf6JnuApCmFTThF3qiwQ82HLS4OjNcHJkKRjxsDVC3aWhcyd7N9N30pWK5vzPCnaxAy1_3u0mHbByY_HMROuixXF07hw
public key (PEM format):
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIGbMBAGByqGSM49AgEGBSuBBAAjA4GGAAQBm3GiQ0HmPdCyeuy7yWnxjwlQnjn9
dytNIqD/nsuhX1SVuDFH2iD12SM+csYrqLAwZKP4Y3BNIH+5QUFgpbCBwEEBu3w6
FeqM/5rJvxjG2/YJU2p1aUGed8Br/bZVEFVN6ohWgFGrC/hXxYuxVVwIwuzXnd8N
bXCVGZZeVKM5YrbcZQM=
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----

If I use java client (nimbus-jose-jwt) to create and sign JWT, verification is stable.
Do I use jsrsasign library incorrectly?
There is another JavaScript library: https://github.com/panva/jose.
Unfortunately, I can't import it to Postman.

Looks to me like a bug in the jsrsasign library (at least for P-521), where the two signature parts r and s are not correctly brought to the required length of 66 (for P-521) bytes each (padding with leading 0x00 values if the values are too short, truncating the leading 0x00 sign byte if the values are too long). You can try to fix this for the incorrect signatures, but due to the lack of uniqueness regarding r and s this will probably not always work.

If you post the public key (belonging to the posted signatures), it would be possible to verify this assumption.

@Topaco posted the public key

With this public key I cannot verify any of the two signatures even with jsrsasign. Since this works for signatures when I use my own key pair, this indicates that the posted public key does not match.

I updated it. Probably i pasted it incorrectly. It is a public key in PEM format.

No, the posted signatures cannot be verified with this key, convince yourself online https://jsfiddle.net/b9g8q64f/: While your signatures cannot be verified, the signatures (both the formally valid 132 and the invalid 130 bytes) can be verified with my key pair. Thus, the public key you posted does not seem to belong to either of the signatures. So I can't check if the above fix works for the 130 bytes signatures. But you can try it yourself.

Now they are verified in https://jsfiddle.net/h1nztydc/1/. I changed signatures.

As already suspected in the comment, the jsrsasign library seems to have a bug when converting the ECDSA signature to P1363 format, at least for curve P-521. In the P1363 format, the r and s values are represented as unsigned, big-endian and concatenated. For P-521, r and s are each 66 bytes in size. If a value is shorter, it is brought to 66 bytes with leading 0x00 values, so that the signature has a constant length of 132 bytes. This is necessary so that the r and s values are clearly identifiable.
For the posted 130 bytes signature, the padding is missing for both the r and the s value, i.e. r-length/s-length = 65bytes/65bytes, as can easily be checked if the invalid signature (spaces only for display purposes):
Base64url: -GJ6N27KEqRKHgmdyRIApgN6861cFbAXtksTPv3GVDVV-80Jjm266tiQqh3ORfLt_ucijNoKlvdZ8b90H1nb7SQSj3Mo0JZT8-Ht6fP9DA13LsWdTQuX7TTIUEqPegAI9lCmgZMFpbNeGqVarsOfgSIrpFvp7rFCdo7aFM7OaShGKw
hex:       f8627a376eca12a44a1e099dc91200a6037af3ad5c15b017b64b133efdc6543555fbcd098e6dbaead890aa1dce45f2edfee7228cda0a96f759f1bf741f59dbed24 128f7328d09653f3e1ede9f3fd0c0d772ec59d4d0b97ed34c8504a8f7a0008f650a6819305a5b35e1aa55aaec39f81222ba45be9eeb142768eda14cece6928462b

is manually fixed:
hex:       00f8627a376eca12a44a1e099dc91200a6037af3ad5c15b017b64b133efdc6543555fbcd098e6dbaead890aa1dce45f2edfee7228cda0a96f759f1bf741f59dbed24 00128f7328d09653f3e1ede9f3fd0c0d772ec59d4d0b97ed34c8504a8f7a0008f650a6819305a5b35e1aa55aaec39f81222ba45be9eeb142768eda14cece6928462b
Base64url: APhiejduyhKkSh4JnckSAKYDevOtXBWwF7ZLEz79xlQ1VfvNCY5tuurYkKodzkXy7f7nIozaCpb3WfG_dB9Z2-0kABKPcyjQllPz4e3p8_0MDXcuxZ1NC5ftNMhQSo96AAj2UKaBkwWls14apVquw5-BIiukW-nusUJ2jtoUzs5pKEYr

The fixed token is then:
eyJhbGciOiJFUzUxMiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJhZTA3YmE1My0xOTYwLTRiMDYtYTYyZi01ZjdkYjRkYWM3MGYiLCJhdWQiOiJkMF9ha0IyNWJZaDNtI1ByekVmPHVLMXZRTGp7Q3hweUdIUHRMWkwpIiwic3ViIjoib3BlbmFwaS1yZXF1ZXN0IiwicmJoIjoiY2FyZ3VqY3lINHJiSDl0U3BxVWo4dFpkZmM0eHUyL1dvOGZJbzJYek1Nbz0iLCJleHAiOjE3MjI4NTAxMzJ9.APhiejduyhKkSh4JnckSAKYDevOtXBWwF7ZLEz79xlQ1VfvNCY5tuurYkKodzkXy7f7nIozaCpb3WfG_dB9Z2-0kABKPcyjQllPz4e3p8_0MDXcuxZ1NC5ftNMhQSo96AAj2UKaBkwWls14apVquw5-BIiukW-nusUJ2jtoUzs5pKEYr

This token is now valid and will be verified as valid by any JWS compliant library, see e.g. here online at jwt.io.

However, this fix is not 100% reliable. Theoretically, r and s values of different lengths are also possible (e.g. r-length/s-length = 66bytes/64bytes). Due to the lack of unambiguity, it is not possible to determine a priori which case applies, so this must be tried out. However, the assumption of an r-length/s-length = 65bytes/65bytes signature is plausible, since the probability of a shorter signature is smaller (as the following estimate makes plausible: probability of a leading 0x00 value: 1/256, two leading 0x00 values: 1/256^2 ...).
Apart from this, other (invalid) signature sizes, such as 131 bytes, are also theoretically conceivable. Here you can only try out which of the parts has to be padded.
Whether these theoretically possible cases actually occur, however, ultimately depends on the bug and cannot be answered without further code analysis. In my tests, I only ever found the lengths 130 and 132 bytes in 1000 generated signatures. However, I sporadically received an error message unknown ECDSA sig s length error when signing, which indicates a greater complexity of the bug.
In my opinion, the most reasonable solution is to switch to another library (at least for P-521). If you cannot find one for your environment, the manual fix described above is an alternative.
